# How to sort alphabetically in custom ListView

Tags: java, android, sorting, listview, android-listview

I need sort alphabetically in my custom ListView. In list_item, I have TextImage and two TextView (app name, package name) and can't understand how sort by alphabet app name:

My list item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/app_icon"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_app_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="Application name"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_app_package"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="app.package.name"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And my adapter:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

    private Context context;
    private List mItem;
    private PackageManager packageManager;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int list_item, List items) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, items);

        this.context = context;
        this.mItem = items;
        packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    }


    public int getCount(){
        return ((null != mItem) ? mItem.size() : 0);
    }

    @Override
    public ApplicationInfo getItem(int position) {
        return (null != mItem) ? (ApplicationInfo) mItem.get(position) : null;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position){
        return position;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        View view = convertView;

        if (null == view) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        ApplicationInfo data = (ApplicationInfo) mItem.get(position);

        if (null != data){
            TextView appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_app_name);
            TextView appPackage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_app_package);
            ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);

            appName.setText(data.loadLabel(packageManager));
            appPackage.setText(data.packageName);
            icon.setImageDrawable(data.loadIcon(packageManager));
        }


        return view;
    }
}
```

My fragment in which show ListView

```
public class ResultFragment extends ListFragment {
    private PackageManager packageManager = null;
    private ListViewAdapter listViewAdapter = null;

    private List mItem;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        packageManager = getContext().getPackageManager();

        new LoadApplications().execute();
    }


    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = (ApplicationInfo) mItem.get(position);

        try{
            Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(applicationInfo.packageName);
            if (intent != null){
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLauncherIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list){

        ArrayList mItem = new ArrayList();

        for(ApplicationInfo info : list) {
            try{
                if(packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName) != null) {
                    mItem.add(info);
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return mItem;
    }

    private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
            mItem = checkForLauncherIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));

            listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, mItem);


            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
            setListAdapter(listViewAdapter);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), null, "Loading file info...");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
    }

}
```

Please help me by sorting my list alphabetically.

Comment: so what do you have problems with? you dont know what determines the sort order in a `ListView`?

Comment: Sort the adapter. Better if you get it already sorted (i.e.: using an ORDER BY clause in your db query)

Comment: @user3729037    check my answer

Comment: @user3729037 check my answer it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From Android Documentation**

> **public abstract android.content.Intent
>   getLaunchIntentForPackage(java.lang.String packageName)**
>
> Returns a
>   "good" intent to launch a front-door activity in a package. This is
>   used, for example, to implement an "open" button when browsing through
>   packages. The current implementation looks first for a main activity
>   in the category Intent.CATEGORY_INFO, and next for a main activity in
>   the category Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER. Returns null if neither are
>   found.
>
> Parameters: packageName - The name of the package to inspect.
>
> Returns: A fully-qualified Intent that can be used to launch the main
>   activity in the package. Returns null if the package does not contain
>   such an activity, or if packageName is not recognized.

You need to make some changes in your code

```
private ArrayList<ResolveInfo> checkForLauncherIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list){

    ArrayList<ResolveInfo> mItems = new ArrayList();

    for(ApplicationInfo info : list) {
        try{
            if(packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName) != null) {
                Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName));
ResolveInfo app = packageManager.resolveActivity(intent,0);
mItems.add(app);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return mItems;
}
```

in your asn task

```
private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
       ArrayList<ResolveInfo> mItem = checkForLauncherIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));

      listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(ctx, mItem);


        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ResolveInfo resolveInfo = listViewAdapter.getItem(position);
                ActivityInfo activityInfo = resolveInfo.activityInfo;
                ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName,activityInfo.name);

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setComponent(name);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        //progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), null, "Loading file info...");

    }
}
```

In your adapter constructor

```
 public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ResolveInfo> mItem;
    private PackageManager packageManager;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ResolveInfo> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mItem = items;
        packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        Collections.sort(mItem,new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(packageManager));
    }


    public int getCount(){
        return mItem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ResolveInfo getItem(int position) {
        return mItem.get(position);
    }
    public long getItemId(int position){
        return position;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        if (convertView  == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.testa, null);
        }

        ResolveInfo app =  mItem.get(position);

        TextView appName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_app_name);
        TextView appPackage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_app_package);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);

        ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;

        appPackage.setText(activity.applicationInfo.packageName);
        appName.setText(app.loadLabel(packageManager));
        icon.setImageDrawable(app.loadIcon(packageManager));



        return convertView;
    }
}
```

[image: helping]

**Find the entire project [At Github](https://github.com/gikarasojo/listing-all-apps/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/crusar/helpinguser/MainActivity.java)**

Answer (score 0):

First change  The Chinese to pinyin you can use the jar [pinyin4j-2.5.0.jar](http://pinyin4j.sourceforge.net/)
then maybe you can try this method
`Arrays.sort(arrayList,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);`

Comment: `Arrays.sort()` sorts arrays, not `ArrayList`s.

Answer (score 0):

Do this it will work

Create a class comparator like this

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<ApplicationInfo> {
        @Override
        public int compare(ApplicationInfo o1, ApplicationInfo o2) {
            return o1.loadLabel(packageManager).toString().compareTo(o2.loadLabel(packageManager).toString());
        }
    }
```

Now use this class in the Async Task where you are creating the adapter

```
Collections.sort(mItem, new CustomComparator());
listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(context, mItem);
```

it will sort your list

Let me know in case of more issue

Comment: @user3729037 have you check my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

use this method when you need to sort in listview,

```
Collections.sort(apps, new Comparator<App>() {

                @Override
                public int compare(App lhs, App rhs) {
                         //here getTitle() method return app name...
                    return lhs.getTitle().compareTo(rhs.getTitle());

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

````
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<UserInfo> userInfos;
    private CustomListAdapter customListAdapter;
    private ListView customListView;
    private String[] names={
            "3 Khan",
            "2 Ahmed",
            "1 Iqbal"

    };
    private String[] professions={
            "Rank 1",
            "Rank 2",
            "Rank 3"

    };
    private int[] photos={
            R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_6

    };




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
        customListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.custom_list_view);
        userInfos=new ArrayList<>();
        Arrays.sort(names,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        customListAdapter=new CustomListAdapter(userInfos,this);
        customListView.setAdapter(customListAdapter);
        getDatas();
        customListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Name : " + names[i] + "\n Profession : " + professions[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    // getting all the datas
    private void getDatas(){
        for(int count=0;count<names.length;count++){
            userInfos.add(new UserInfo(names[count],professions[count],photos[count]));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_option,menu);
        MenuItem menuItem=menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        SearchView searchView=(SearchView)menuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                newText=newText.toString();
                ArrayList<UserInfo> newUserInfos=new ArrayList<>();

                for(UserInfo userInfo:userInfos){
                    String name=userInfo.getName().toLowerCase();
                    String profession=userInfo.getProfession().toLowerCase();
                    if(name.contains(newText) || profession.contains(newText)){
                        newUserInfos.add(userInfo);
                    }
                }
                customListAdapter.filterResult(newUserInfos);
                customListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return false;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}```
````